# Open document in tabcontent on Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Below code I use group to show activity in tabcontent on TabHost:

```
File file = new File(FilePath);
String mimetype = mime_type(FileName);

Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
it.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);
it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
Window w = group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("Docaument", it);  
View view = w.getDecorView();  
group.setContentView(view);
```

I want to let the activity of document reader app place inside the tabcontent.
But not full screen.
How can I do it?